# JQuery.getJSON() reading a local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-files

How do you read a file in the current directory using JQuery.getJSON()?

I'm trying something simple (with my data.json file in the same directory as my html file):

```
$.getJSON("./data.json")
```

and I get the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Projects/test/data.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of path, but it doesn't seem to work...

EDIT:  I'm using Chrome, but I'd like to work in all browsers...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome, it is intentional that AJAX on `file:///` paths never works.

[crbug/40787](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to installing a local LAMP server is to use python's simple HTTP server. As long as you have python installed, just open up bash and use the python interpreter.

For python 2 use:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

For python 3 use:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

Then just point your browser at localhost:8000 and you shouldn't have any trouble accessing the file if it's in the same directory.

Comment: although 8000 is default port no need to mention it if you don't want to change port.

Comment: Thank you, this is great

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're running your web files directly from your hard drive. There are various pitfalls in this, one of which you have found. Ideally you want to be working in a server environment, even locally. You can install a (free) local LAMP server such as [XAMPP](http://www.xampp.org). Then, you'll be able to use local AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about path

It's a cross-domain problem

Basically you need to add a callback in your URL, so that jQuery can automatically change the request type from json to jsonp

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) for detail