# How would I transform a shape into another shape in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've just started using d3.js (about 1.5 weeks in).  I was wondering -- most of the examples use some pattern like

```
mysvg.selectAll("rect").data(mydata,key).transition()...;
```

Right now my code looks like the following.  I want to be able to draw a time series as rectangles for the points that are after a certain time and lines if they are before a certain time.  I know it's possible to just have them as one series and apply filters, but I was wondering if there is a better way in which I can just draw the series using one select statement.

If not, how can I implement it using filters? Particularly, I'm confused as to how to use the exit so that the bars disappear as I increase time.  I've tried several different ways of alling .exit().remove(), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function drawChart(svgarea,mydata,key)
{   

var g = svgarea.append("svg:g");


var rects = g.selectAll("rect").data(mydata,key).enter().append("rect");
var lines = g.selectAll("line").data(mydata,key).enter().append("line");

drawAxis();

chartData = [];
chartData.redraw = function(timeIndex)
{                       
    rects.filter(function(d){
            var isAfter =  ...;
            return isAfter;})
        .transition().duration(500)
                    .attr(...,...);});  
    lines.filter(function(d){
            var isBefore =  ...;
            return isBefore;})
        .transition().duration(500)
                    .attr(...,...);});
    rects.exit().remove();  
}
chartData.redraw(0);
return chartData;
}
```

Note:  I set it up like this because the data is non-static.  The user of this little graph will call chart.redraw() after an update to the data has been made (at least that's the idea)

Comment: @user11 .. you haved received some good answer to a couple of your questions (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297219/jquery-getjson-reading-a-local-file) ; please consider going through your questions and accept good answers that helped you.

Comment: Sorry -- I thought I accepted that answer.  I'll try to be more vigilant about giving credit where it's due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your data *before* you join it with your selection. Keep in mind that many of the iteration methods in d3, including `filter`, are based off of methods provided by the `Array` Object in JavaScript.

```
rectData = myData.filter(function(d) { /* filter conditions */ }
lineData = myData.filter(function(d) { /* filter conditions */ }
```

More info: `array.filter(callback[, thisObject])`

Then, you can just focus on `update` and `enter()` without having to filter your data every time you redraw.

Comment: To be honest, it shouldn't matter. Each time you pull new data, you would still want to follow the same techniques of filtering it before joining it.

Comment: Also, by filtering the data, the transition from a bar to a line isn't smooth (the bar disappears, and the line flys in the from the top left)

Comment: yeah, i was able to fix this by filtering, it's just the animation isn't smooth