# Get-Json form local file

Tags: javascript, getjson

I'm working on a small server (NodeJS environment) to get JSON data from a URL and a local file to compare these.

I'm using 'get-json' to load the JSON form the url and get some values, unfortunately
it doesn't work for the local file.

I tried it with 'request' too.

```
var getJSON = require('get-json')
var localpath = "./location/file.json"

getJSON(localpath, function(data, allowed_content) {
  var a = allowed_content[0].age;
  var b = allowed_content[1].age;
  var c = allowed_content[2].age;
  var d = allowed_content[5].age;
  var e = allowed_content[6].age;
});
```

I can't figure it out why the local path isn't working.

Comment: Are you trying to do it in browser or in node.js environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery.getJSON() reading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297219/jquery-getjson-reading-a-local-file)

Comment: In NodeJS environment

Comment: Read this : https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/

Comment: Just FYI, I removed the `local-storage` tag, because that refers to the `localStorage` object in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) function

```
var localpath = "./location/file.json"
    fetch(localpath)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr don't use `get-json` to read local files but use `readFile`

`get-json` is for network request, its docs says it wraps around `requests` in node, and uses *JSONP* on the browser.
To read a local file just use `readFile` or `readFileSync`:

```
var { readFileSync } = require("fs");
var localPath = "";
var localFile = readFileSync(localPath, "utf8"); // utf8 is opts and depends on your setup, the async version of readFile takes a callback as last argument
console.log(JSON.parse(localFile));
```

Comment: It's working, now I need to figure out how I can get the specific values from the value. like "allowed_content[6].age"

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Calling `JSON.parse` on a string should return a JS object (or throw an error). Name the output `allowed_content` and you can access all its properties using regular syntax

Comment: I mean, I need specific values from the JSON file. I'll try to figure it out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ah, good luck with this. If you have a memory limit issue you might be interested in http://oboejs.com/ wich is a json streaming library. If my answer is OK can you accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was real easy actually:

```
var myvar = require('./filepath/myfile.json');
var a = myvar[0].age;
var b = myvar[1].age;
var c = myvar[2].age;
var d = myvar[5].age;
var e = myvar[6].age;
```